# Possible to "move" a C variable address to start of .rodata in .elf binary executable?

Tags: c, gcc, elf

Consider the following .c files:

`main.c`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ext.h"

const char greeting[] = "hello world";
const char greeting_two[] = "another hello";

int main() {
    printf("%s!\n", greeting);
    printf("%s!\n", greeting_two);
    printf("%s!\n", mystring_one);
    printf("%s!\n", mystring_two);
    return 0;
}
```

`ext.h`

```c
extern const char mystring_one[];
extern const char mystring_two[];
```

`ext.c`

```c
const char mystring_one[] = "my string one";
const char mystring_two[] = "my string two";
```

I compile this with:

```bash
gcc -c -g main.c -o main.o
gcc -c -g ext.c -o ext.o
gcc -o main.exe main.o ext.o
```

... and I can observe the layout of `.rodata` section with:

```
$ readelf -p .rodata ./main.exe 

String dump of section '.rodata':
  [     8]  hello world
  [    18]  another hello
  [    26]  %s!^J
  [    30]  my string one
  [    40]  my string two
```

Is it possible to somehow hint to the `gcc` compiler (either in the source code, or via gcc/linker switch), to (say) store the value of `mystring_two` as first in the `.rodata` section, so we would get this output:

```
$ readelf -p .rodata ./main.exe 

String dump of section '.rodata':
  [     8]  my string two
  [    ww]  hello world
  [    xx]  another hello
  [    yy]  %s!^J
  [    zz]  my string one
```

...?

Comment: I am extremely curious why you would need to do this.

Comment: @sj95126 - I want to have `__DATE__` or `__TIME__` (or similar identification stuff) first there, so when I double-check my .elf from the command line, I can just do `readelf -p .rodata program.elf | head -3` and see immediately from the command line what does elf have stored inside.

Comment: Fair enough, but couldn't you also just generate a special string that starts with "SpecialBuildTimestampThatCantBeConfusedWithAnythingElse" and `grep` for that from the output of `readelf` ?

Comment: @sj95126 - you're right - I've tried that, and that demands first parsing `readelf -a` and finding relative offset address, then using that to grep in `readelf -p .rodata` (from my limited knowledge of readelf, this is the only thing I could find); but this question regardless popped in my mind while thinking about this, so I was wondering if such a mechanism was there.

Comment: What stated by @sj95126 can be grepped even without readelf. See grep -a ...

Comment: Define a section and do section placement.  https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_mono/ld.html